# How to make Android HTC Desire app fit screen of Samsung Galaxy pad?

Tags: android

Have app displaying fine on HTC Desire,
but on Samsung Galaxy pad it does not fill the screen space.

**How do I make my Android HTC Desire app fill the screen of Samsung Galaxy pad ?**

*Details:*
*Layoutfile for start activity:*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

*Resource folders*
are filled with same size PNG files (not scaled down):
res/drawable-hdpi
res/drawable-mdpi
res/drawable-ldpi
res/drawable

*Androidmanifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="my.package" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application android:name="my.package.AppContext" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
```

*default.properties*

```
# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8
```

Comment: Have now tried <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false" /> w.o. any success.

Comment: THIS SOLVED IT:  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  The way I interpret the documentation I should not have to specify this.  
It should be default values !?

Comment: you should answer your own question - transform your comments into an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

THIS SOLVED IT:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```